# Разместить в одну колонку

Tags: css, html5

Привет, у меня есть свёрстанный блок, но элементы(круги) не стоят друг под другом, как это исправить?

```css
.about{
    margin-top: 86px;
}
 
.timeline-holder {
  position: relative;
}
 
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 60px 0;
}
 
.box .left {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
 
.box .right {
    direction: rtl;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
 
.box:nth-child(even) { 
  margin-right: calc(50% - 75px);
}
 
.box:nth-child(odd) {  
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 75px);
```

```html
<section id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>
                    About Us
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-holder">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="left">
                        <h3>July 2018 <span>Our humble beginnings</span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/about1.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="right">
                        <h3>January 2018 <span>Our humble beginnings</span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</p></div>
                    <img src="img/about2.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="left">
                        <h3>December 2018 <span>Our humble beginnings</span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</p></div>
                    <img src="img/about3.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="right">
                        <h3>February 2019 <span>Our humble beginnings</span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</p></div>
                    <img src="img/about4.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stackoferflow! (+)

Comment: .box {
margin.... : calc(50% - 75px)
}

75px = 50% от ширины картинки

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант сделать эту страницу в 3 колонки, 1 - текст слева, 2 круги отцентрованные, 3 - текст справа.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Тоже о чем писал Музыка Сергей, только с картинками

```css
.about{
    margin-top: 86px;
}
 
.timeline-holder {
  position: relative;
}
 
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 60px 0;
}
 
.box img{
  width:150px;
}
.box .left {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
 
.box .right {
    direction: rtl;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
 
.box:nth-child(even) { 
  margin-right: calc(50% - 75px);
}
 
.box:nth-child(odd) {  
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 75px);
```

```html
<section id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>
                    About Us
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-holder">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="left">
                        <h3>July 2018 <span>Our humble beginnings</span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="http://apikabu.ru/img_n/2012-11_3/dy4.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="right">
                        <h3>January 2018 <span>Our humble beginnings</span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</p></div>
                    <img src="http://apikabu.ru/img_n/2012-11_3/dy4.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="left">
                        <h3>December 2018 <span>Our humble beginnings</span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</p></div>
                    <img src="http://apikabu.ru/img_n/2012-11_3/dy4.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="right">
                        <h3>February 2019 <span>Our humble beginnings</span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</p></div>
                    <img src="http://apikabu.ru/img_n/2012-11_3/dy4.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```